# How to register(install) as service java application with JSVC wrapper on MacOS X

Tags: macos, daemon, apache-commons, jsvc

I have an application which i want to run as service on MacOS X. I used JSVC as wrapper and currently it starts in console just fine, shutdown process is correct, etc. So now i have to register it as service. Found some manuals, wrote .plist file. Next i executed

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/my.service.plist
sudo launchctl start my.service
```

And nothing happened. Service didn't started.

plist contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>my.service</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
<string>/servertest/MYService</string>
<string>-jvm</string>
<string>server</string>
<string>-outfile</string>
<string>out.txt</string>
<string>-errfile</string>
<string>err.txt</string>
<string>-verbose</string>
<string>-debug</string>
<string>-home</string>
<string>/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home</string>
<string>-cp</string>
<string>./lib/hsqldb.jar:./lib/my-wrapper.jar:./lib/commons-daemon-1.0.8.jar</string>
<string>my.service.DaemonMac</string>
</array>
<key>WorkingDirectory</key>
<string>/servertest</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/servertest/stdout.log</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/servertest/stderr.log</string>
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<false/>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if yuu try using absolute paths not relative ones

Comment: I use absolute paths in plist. Relative ones are arguments passed to JVM. It doesn't matter, i tried absolute paths everywhere and got same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, nobody knows, i guess. Anyway, i handled it myself. Here's example which worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>myserver</string>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <true/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/opt/MYServer/MYServer</string>
        <string>-server</string>
        <string>-outfile</string>
        <string>/opt/MYServer/out.txt</string>
        <string>-errfile</string>
        <string>/opt/MYServer/err.txt</string>
        <string>-verbose</string>
        <string>-debug</string>
        <string>-nodetach</string>
        <string>-home</string>
        <string>/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home</string>
        <string>-cp</string>
        <string>/opt/MYServer/lib/hsqldb.jar:/opt/MYServer/lib/my-wrapper.jar:/opt/MYServer/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.8.jar</string>
        <string>my.service.DaemonMac</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/opt/MYServer/stderr.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/opt/MYServer/stdout.log</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/opt/MYServer</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: So what was different? Your own parameters getting absolute paths, something else? It would be easier for us readers to see the diff that made the above plist work.

Comment: @akauppi I would certainly reworked my answer if you asked two years ago. But since this question isn't interesting enough for broad publicity to achieve any upvotes I won't bother to make a diff and to recall what was wrong. Pardon me for that :-)

Comment: absolutely understood :)